# add www to htaccess for contextdependant urls

Tags: .htaccess, variables

I know about his

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.net$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.net/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, i do not know beforehand what the domainname will be (it can be one of about 30). Is it possible make yourdomain.com variable so it matches all 30 possible domains?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need to match those 30 domains:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: brilliant :-) If i had > 15 rep, i'd vote you up. but i am on 11 atm.